# Any reason for deprecating shutdown method?

Tags: akka

When shuting down an ActorSystem I found that `ActorSystem::shutdown` was deprecated. It's suggested `"Use the terminate() method instead"`.

But the decumentation of those methods is almost the same:

```
  /**
   * Terminates this actor system. This will stop the guardian actor, which in turn
   * will recursively stop all its child actors, then the system guardian
   * (below which the logging actors reside) and the execute all registered
   * termination handlers (see [[ActorSystem#registerOnTermination]]).
   * Be careful to not schedule any operations on completion of the returned future
   * using the `dispatcher` of this actor system as it will have been shut down before the
   * future completes.
   */
  def terminate(): Future[Terminated]
```

and

```
  /**
   * Stop this actor system. This will stop the guardian actor, which in turn
   * will recursively stop all its child actors, then the system guardian
   * (below which the logging actors reside) and the execute all registered
   * termination handlers (see [[ActorSystem#registerOnTermination]]).
   */
  @deprecated("Use the terminate() method instead", "2.4")
  def shutdown(): Unit
```

with one exception that the return type has changed. What was the reason of deprecating `shutdown`? Was it not safe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the deprecation was to follow the "terminate" convention used in other areas of the project, as well as exposing termination events.

The important part is the termination events:

> The termination hooks allow system actors to perform final cleanup before the system shuts down or restarts - in this particular case it's to let remote systems know that any remote-deployed actors on the shutting down system are dead, but there are other cases where this gets used inside Akka core

See the following for more information:

- [The related Akka issue](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/15757)
- [The related Akka.NET issue](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/327)
- [The Actor system shutdown section of their 2.3 to 2.4 migration guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/project/migration-guide-2.3.x-2.4.x.html#Actor_system_shutdown)

Comment: Well, I thought that everything about actors is asynchronous (including the `shutdown` method). We want to be lock free. BTW what "terminate convention" do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, that was poor wording on my part... I've updated the answer.

Comment: Cool, the related issue link explains that. Thank you. In short, it's done for finer-grained termination control, right?